# Conditionally extend systemd reboot timeout

Tags: systemd

TL;DR: I'm trying to construct a mechanism to defer any requested reboot until a specific, sensitive process has finished its job.

---

In systemd, `reboot.target` has a default `JobTimeoutSec=30min`, and `JobTimeoutAction=force-reboot`.

I have a task which has an `ExecStop` action which needs to be able to complete uninterrupted. Consequently, this service has a `TimeoutStopSec=infinity`; however, if this stop action is blocking the scheduling of `reboot.target`, the `JobTimeout` on `reboot.target` will eventually cause a reboot to be forced even if the stop action is still running.

---

My current attempt at working around this was to build an overlay for `reboot.target` which replaces the default `JobTimeoutAction=force-reboot` with `JobTimeoutAction=exit`, and adds an `OnFailure` event; something like the following:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/reboot.target.d/defer-if-critical-job-running.conf
[Unit]
JobTimeoutAction=exit
FailureActionExitStatus=1
OnFailure=reboot-now-unless-critical-job-is-running.service
```

```
# /etc/systemd/system/reboot-now-unless-critical-job-is-running.service
[Unit]
Description=Reboot unless a critical job is running
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'if systemctl is-active some-critical-job.service; then systemctl reboot; else systemctl reboot --force; fi'
```

However, this doesn't actually work: We still do a force-reboot immediately when the `JobTimeout` on `reboot.target` is reached.

How can I indefinitely defer a reboot, but *only* when a specific critical job is running?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but have you considered adding a `your-job-stopped.target` and **add** to `systemd-reboot.service`: `Requires=your-job-stopped.target` and `After=your-job-stopped.target`? And reach that target once your job has exited safely. If my understanding of that part of systemd is correct, it should wait before proceeding. The required should prevent it's start until the requirement is met. [Also see](https://serverfault.com/a/812589/382224)